# How do you initialize a Quill Editor in an Angular 2 Component?

Tags: node.js, angular, typescript, quill

I am trying to implement my own Quill editor component in my Angular 2 project. I used npm to install quill into my project. I am trying to create a word counter application with my component. I am trying to implement the code from :https://quilljs.com/blog/building-a-custom-module/

HTML Code:

```
<div id="editor"></div>
<div id="counter">0</div>
```

CSS:

```
body {
  padding: 25px;
}

#editor {
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
}

#counter {
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  border-width: 0px 1px 1px 1px;
  color: #aaa;
  padding: 5px 15px;
  text-align: right;
}
```

This is my Component code:

```
import { OnInit, Component, ViewChild, ElementRef } from '@angular/core';

import * as Quill from 'quill';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-quill-editor',
  templateUrl: './quill-editor.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./quill-editor.component.css']
})
export class QuillEditorComponent{
// Implement and register module

  constructor()
  {
          Quill.register('modules/counter', function(quill, options) {
            var container = document.querySelector('#counter');
            quill.on('text-change', function() {
              var text = quill.getText();
              // There are a couple issues with counting words
              // this way but we'll fix these later
              container.innerHTML = text.split(/\s+/).length;
            });
          });

          console.log(document.querySelector('#editor'))

          // We can now initialize Quill with something like this:
          var quill = new Quill('#editor', {
            modules: {
              counter: true
            }
          });
  }
}
```

When I serve my application, I receive:

```
quill Invalid Quill container #editor
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can check Angular lifecycle and invoke your Quill-related stuff there, putting them in constructor() might cause error since the HTML elements are not yet rendered.

You can try putting them in ngOnInit() or ngAfterViewInit()

```
export class QuillComponent implements OnInit {
    constructor() {
    }

    ngOnInit() { // Quill initialization and querying for elements here }
}
```

Reference : https://angular.io/guide/lifecycle-hooks

**4th March 2019**

Another approach that can be done for this are :

- If you element is a ViewChild , then using the Lifecycle as above should help
- If you would like your current element to be the editor , trying inject ElementRef might do as well

Comment: Hi, I am having a similar issue over at: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61667844/initialising-quill-as-part-of-an-angular-component. Can you please help?